# Close to a projection implies almost idempotent in C*-Algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection

I have the following problem:
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra, let $x\in A$ be self-adjoint and let $p\in A$ be a projection, i.e. $p^*=p=p^2$. Moreover, assume that $||x-p||<\frac{1}{16}$.

Claim: $||x^2-x||<\frac{1}{4}$.

I know that the result is true, it comes up in a proof about the relation of UHF-Algebras and supernatural numbers. However, I don't know how to prove it, because $||x^2-x||\leq||x^2-p^2||+||p-x||$ does hold, but I don't succeed in bounding $||x^2-p^2||$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\|p\|=1$ unless $p=0$.
$$
\|x^2-x\| = \|(x-p)^2 - (x-p) + xp+px-2p\| \le \|x-p\|^2 + \|x-p\| + \|xp+px-2p\|
$$
$$
=\|x-p\|^2 + \|x-p\| + \|(x-p)p + p(x-p)\|  \le \|x-p\|^2 + \|x-p\| + 2\|x-p\|
$$
$$
< (1/16)^2+3/16  < 1/4.
$$